# How to specify a Parent post type for a Child post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to register a custom post type as child of another custom post type. I have 2 questions--

1. `hierarchical' => true` should be added on the parent or child when
   register?
2. Codex says "Allows Parent to be specified", how?

Answer (score 2):

"Allows Parent to be specified" means that the post type behaves more like pages than posts.

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with core functions, but there's a plugin wich does almost the same.

I recommend you the powerful [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin by WordPress Core Contributor scribu. It allows you to create connections between different post types and has lots of configuration possibilities. The screenshots and the [documentation](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) can give you an impression if it's right for your task.

Comment: Nice plugin, but a bit too heavy for me and I need to do a lot more specific tasks for my needs between the connections. Anyway, I'm going to study this plugin to get some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Allows Parent to be specified" means that you can allow its child post types to call this post type their parent. This means you need to add

> 'hierarchical' => true

every time in the args of parent Post Type when you need children.

Look at [this](http://janina.tumblr.com/post/3588081423/post-parent-different-type) for making a 'Post Type' a child of another.